# Jhipster can not select API first development using swagger-codegen

Tags: swagger, jhipster

I'm going thru the Jhipster and can't select some option. How could I have it selectable? Why I can't select the 'API first development using swagger-codegen' option?

These are the console steps after running jhipster command:

1. Check your Internet connection.
2. If you are using an HTTP proxy, try this command: git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
   ? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Microservice application
   ? What is the base name of your application? service1
   ? As you are running in a microservice architecture, on which port would like your server to run? It should be unique to avoid port conflicts. 8086
   ? What is your default Java package name? com.comp.abc.service1
   ? Which service discovery server do you want to use? JHipster Registry (uses Eureka, provides Spring Cloud Config support and monitoring dashboards)
   ? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
   ? Which *type* of database would you like to use? No database
   ? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven
   ? Which other technologies would you like to use?
   ❯◯ API first development using swagger-codegen
   ◯ Asynchronous messages using Apache Kafka

Answer (score 1):

To select answers on multiple choices questions you need to press the spacebar.